# Jquery get TypeError: undefined is not an object In Safari but ok in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I use this jquery to select a div `document.querySelectorAll('.select-items > div:nth-child(3)')[6].click();`

so there is 7 select dropdown list, i select the 6th dropdown and 3th element div `

if i replace 3th child by 1 or 2 it works well, but not in 3th

but in safari i got

> "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelectorAll('.select-items > div:nth-child(3)')[6].click')"

In Chrome works fine, the app i use need safari web kit so no way to use chrome.

```
<td class="selector">
                                    <div class="custom-select">
                                        <select id="option_600_pid_144" class="pid_144 validation-passed" original-title="" style="visibility: visible;">
                                            <option id="option_600_pid_144_nochoice" order="0" class="optionFireChangeEvent_144" value="">Faites votre choix...</option>
                                                                                                <option order="1" id="option_600_pid_144_638" class="optionFireChangeEvent_144" value="638">Blumotion</option>
                                                                                                <option order="2" id="option_600_pid_144_3115" class="optionFireChangeEvent_144" value="3115" selected="selected">Tip-On + BluMotion</option>
                                                                                        </select>
                                    <div class="select-selected">Tip-On + BluMotion</div><div class="select-items select-hide"><div>Faites votre choix...</div><div>Blumotion</div><div>Tip-On + BluMotion</div></div></div>
                                </td>
```

Console log

[image]

Comment: 1. that's not jQuery, that's just JS 2. what do you get when you do `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.select-items > div:nth-child(3)').length)`?

Comment: 6 and undefined

Comment: isthere is something else that could replace the original script that may work on safari ?

Comment: If the length is 6 then [6] is undefined. Arrays are zero indexed, meaning the sixth element is referenced using [5]. My guess is there's a typo somewhere and therefore the selector only matches 6 dropdowns.

Comment: if i replace 6 by 5 it goes to another dropdown list "document.querySelectorAll('.select-items > div:nth-child(3)')[5].click();"

Comment: funny thing is that if i replace 3 by 2 or 1 "document.querySelectorAll('.select-items > div:nth-child(2)')[6].click();"

it work but i need to select then 3th element

Comment: The number after nth-child is indeed 1 based not zero based. However doing these index selections is inherently unsafe (as you can see). You should use another way to change the option.

Comment: i looked for any other way, and could't find, i ll be happy to try if you have something

Comment: How are the dropdowns populated? Is it all hardcoded? Or are you using a backend? Either way you could add a unique `id` to them and simply use that to select them. You should also set the <select>'s .value instead of clicking on an option. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kecs9bm7/

Comment: Still, the main question is why Safari's list length is only 6 when you have 7 dropdowns.

Comment: it s not my website, i can't add id to the list. have to use as the source code from above :s

Comment: Ok, but again: why does the selector only match 6 divs in Safari but 7 in other browsers? This can only be a caching issue or some weird special character thing, at least I can't think of anything else. Is the website online?

Comment: yes here is the link  bit.ly/3zIpbhw

Comment: This works for me `document.querySelector('#tr_option_553_pid_144 .select-items div:nth-child(3)').click();`

Comment: ooooo Chris danke schon !!!!! amaiziiing  i ll be able to make it all work

Comment: Great, you're welcome :)

Comment: if by any chance you come to Metz let me know

Comment: Haha, will do :)